# Wordpress - Custom Archive Page without pre-posts?

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to disable preloaded posts on a Archive-Page like archive-computers.php?

Example (archive-computers.php):

```
<?php
/**
 * The archive template file
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage mydomain.de
 */
      var_dump($posts);
?>
```

Yes, here i have already posts in $posts. In my case the default posts_per_page => 10.

The problem is i dont need this because iam using here custom-queries on this page. So, how i can disable/prevent this "unused" query. Its waste performance.

Comment: Just delete the line which is calling the posts?

Comment: Sure. Thats easy to unset($posts). But the query is still running. I want to save this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats solves my issue!

```
function _cancel_query( $query ) {

    if ( !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'computer' ) ) {
        $query = false;
    }

    return $query;
}

add_action( 'posts_request', '_cancel_query' );
```